# How to store some context in spring webflux with kotlin coroutines during a request?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, session, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I'm doing a small project and decide not to use spring security for authentication. But how can I store some context in order to access it later elsewhere like SecurityContextHolder? For example, I want to get the current WebSession where doesn't take in WebSession as a parameter. How can I retrive the session?

I tried storing websessions in CoroutineContext in CoWebFilter, but it doesn't work.

```kotlin
data class WebSessionContext(
    val session: WebSession,
    override val key: CoroutineContext.Key<*> = Key,
) : CoroutineContext.Element {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<WebSessionContext>
}

@Component
@Order(-1)
private class AuthenticationFilter(
    private val adminService: AdminService,
    private val authService: AuthService,
) : CoWebFilter() {
    override suspend fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: CoWebFilterChain) {
        val context = coroutineContext + WebSessionContext(exchange.session.awaitSingle())
        log.debug { "Put context $context" }
        withContext(context) {
            chain.filter(exchange)
            println("auth ${coroutineContext[WebSessionContext]}")
        }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
private class RequestLogFilter(private val requestLogRepo: RequestLogRepo) : CoWebFilter() {
    private fun ServerWebExchange.cacheReqBody() = request.body.cache()

    private fun ServerWebExchange.mutateWithCachedReqBody(cachedBody: Flux<DataBuffer>) = mutate()
        .request(CachedBodyRequestDecorator(request, cachedBody)).build()

    override suspend fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: CoWebFilterChain): Unit = coroutineScope {
        val cachedRequestBody = exchange.cacheReqBody()
        val mutatedExchange = exchange.mutateWithCachedReqBody(cachedRequestBody)
        log.debug { "requestlog ${coroutineContext[WebSessionContext.Key]}" }
        with(mutatedExchange.request) {
            val method = method.toString()
            val path = path.toString()
            val params = queryParams.toString()
            val body = DataBufferUtils.join(cachedRequestBody).awaitSingleOrNull()?.toString(Charset.defaultCharset())

            log.debug { "$method $path 请求开始, params: $params body: $body" }
            val time = measureTimeMillis { chain.filter(mutatedExchange) }
            log.info { "$method $path 请求, 耗时: ${time}ms" }

            launch(coroutineContext) { RequestLog(method, path, params, body, time).let(requestLogRepo::save) }
        }
    }
}
```

And log in RequestLogFilter shows null retrieving the websession

Comment: Generally, what you did seems correct - we should use the coroutine context for this. Could you verify `RequestLogFilter` is really running inside the `AuthenticationFilter`? What do you see in logs exactly?

Answer (score 1):

The `suspend fun filter` of a `CoWebFilter` is called with `mono(Dispatchers.Unconfined)`. Because of that the coroutine context is not propagated.

A [commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/b0aa004d9db74b42d7d17883ed490388261ed96e#diff-768490ff11b8eb8598c8c210ff04127ca47d83f18afe88917c3372207c5fa18b) that is/will be in 6.1 allows the coroutine context to propagate to the handler. But seemingly it doesn't propagate from one `CoWebFilter` to another.

---

I'm not that familiar with Spring, but I think you can store the `WebSession` in `exchange.attributes`?